# Finding a probability density from an exponential family using a moment generating function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, moment-generating-functions

I would like to find the density of a sum of i.i.d. random variables $\bar{Y}=\frac{1}{\nu}(Y_1+...+Y_\nu)$, where the density of these random variables is $f_Y(y;\theta)=e^{\theta y - b(\theta)}f_0(y)$. In turn, the density $f_0(y)$ is specified using the m.g.f. $M_0(\xi)=e^{b(\xi)}$ and a differentiable function $b(\xi)$.

**Edit:** Found an additional bit of information that the resulting distribution has to be from the exponential family $f_\bar{Y}(y;\theta, \phi)= \exp{(\frac{y\theta-b(\theta)}{a(\phi)}+c(y, \phi))}$, where $a(\phi)=\nu^{-1}$.

**Attempt 1**:

Omitting the details, I found the m.g.f. of $f_Y(y,\theta)$ to be equal to $M_Y(\xi)=e^{b(\xi + \theta)-b(\theta)}$.

Then, I computed the m.g.f. of the sum of $Y_i$'s using [this property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function#Linear_combination_of_independent_random_variables), which resulted in
$$M_{\bar{Y}}(\xi)=\left(M_Y(\frac{1}{\nu}\xi)\right)^\nu=e^{\nu\left(b(\frac{1}{\nu}\xi+\theta)-b(\theta)\right)}$$
I cannot find a way to transform this into $f_{\hat{Y}}(y; \theta)$ and would greatly appreciate a pointer or a suggestion on how to proceed.

**Attempt 2**:

What seems like a possible solution is to recast $M_{\bar{Y}}$ into the form of $M_Y$ and reconstruct the density from that. For example, if one were to introduce substitutions like $\tilde{b}(\theta)=\nu b(\theta)$ and $\tilde{\xi}=\frac{1}{\nu}\xi$, then the expressions of the two m.g.f.'s would be identical. This means that
$$M_{\bar{Y}}(\tilde{\xi})=
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{\tilde{\xi}y}e^{\theta y-\tilde{b}(\theta)}f_0(y)dy=
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{\tilde{\xi}y}e^{\theta y-\nu b(\theta)}f_0(y)dy.$$
I am not entirely sure how to  deal with $\tilde{\xi}$ at this point... Is it a permissible operation to transform $y$ in the integral into $\tilde{y}=\frac{1}{\nu} y$? It would then follow that
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{\tilde{\xi}y}e^{\theta y-\nu b(\theta)}f_0(y)dy=
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{\xi\tilde{y}}e^{\nu\theta \tilde{y}-\nu b(\theta)}\nu{}f_0(\nu\tilde{y})d\tilde{y}=
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{\xi\tilde{y}}e^{\nu\theta \tilde{y}-\nu b(\theta)+\ln(\nu{}f_0(\nu\tilde{y}))}d\tilde{y}.$$
The density would then be expressed as $f_\hat{Y}(y;\theta, \nu)=e^{\nu(\theta \tilde{y}-b(\theta))+\ln(\nu{}f_0(\nu\tilde{y}))}$ and it would have the form in the desired form mentioned in the **Edit** above.

Would this make sense? My math background is not really so strong, so I have a feeling that I could have made some illegitimate operations here...